# import numpy suddenly stopped working on Jupyter notebook (ImportError: cannot import name 'add_newdocs')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am realtively new to jupyter. I have windows 10 whereby I installed anaconda and simply followed the instruction to download python 3 for jupyter notebook. I enjoy it and started drawing figures and so on but suddenly something happend and jupyter can not import numpy any more

```
import numpy
```

now gives me the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5a0bd626bb1d> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    140         return loader(*packages, **options)
    141 
--> 142     from . import add_newdocs
    143     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

ImportError: cannot import name 'add_newdocs'
```

I tried `conda install numpy` again on command prompt but did not help

Comment: Can you check that `add_newdocs` exists in `D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\`?

Comment: yes i have the file add_newdocs.cpython-36 in D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__pycache__

Comment: Moreover, it seems that in my jupyter notebook python 3 [root] may not be observed anymore

Comment: You may also have stale `.pyc` files / `__pycache__` files. This is somewhat annoying (that is, I don't know an easy way on Windows), but you'll want to remove `__pycache__` directories and remaining `*.pyc` files from the packages installed in `D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages`, and probably your working directory as well. I can't guarantee that works, but it gives you a cleaner start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have updated my Python too many times and therefore it appears that when using jupyter notebook things are being mixed up. Unfortunately, the only way to go around this is to uninstall Anaconda all together and then delete and uninstall all previous Python versions and then fresh reinstall of Anaconda. This has solved my issue. I wish there were an easier solution though!